# Convert .Edi file into an XML file in c# without using a third party dll

Tags: c#, linq, edi

is there anyways to read a ".EDI file" using linq or by using a free version dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution, dude.. just goahead

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11278/EDIFACT-to-XML-to-Anything-You-Want

Comment: You never specified what standard. If you were working with ANSI X12, you'd be SOL with that solution.

Answer (score 0):

EDI is a text file.  XML is a text file.  As long as you know how to read text using LINQ and understand your source file (EDI), and can write out text (XML), then you can code it.  People have written these kinds of translators for all different kind of languages.  There's no reason you couldn't write in with C#.

Many people here are very fond of writing their own translators / parsers.  Since there are many versions of the EDI standard, a "free DLL" that is actively maintained is going to be hard to find.  Developers put a lot of time and effort into their translators, and maintaining syntax and dictionary rules (especially for X12).  EDIFACT might be a little easier to find, since the dictionaries are published, but you didn't specify what standard you're working with.